# NodeJS Appending File differently to source file

Tags: node.js

So I have some code that takes an input file, Replaces strings in that file and appends those replaced strings to another file.

The problem is that the append function outputs a slightly different file (not where the replaces are). The strings are replaced fine its just some of the lines are swapped and some lines do not have a break.

Code:

```js
const settings = require('../settings.json')
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
const sleep = require('system-sleep')
const Promise = require('bluebird');

var eachLine = Promise.promisify(lineReader.eachLine);

const fs = require('fs')

function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
 charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

fs.stat('./unblacklisted.rbxlx', function(err, stat) {
    if(err == null) {
        fs.unlink('./unblacklisted.rbxlx', function(err) {
            if (err) throw err
        })
    } else if(err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        // file does not exist
        
    } else {
        console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
    }
})

eachLine(`./${settings['CorrectMapName/fileName']}`, function(line) {
    if (typeof line.split('referent=')[1] !== 'undefined') {
        let treatedline = line.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        let test = treatedline.split('referent=')[1]
        let hello = (treatedline.replace(test, `"RBX${Buffer.from(makeid(17), 'ascii').toString('hex').toUpperCase()}">`))
        fs.appendFile('./unblacklisted.rbxlx',`${hello}\n`, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    } else {
        let treatedline = line.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        fs.appendFile('./unblacklisted.rbxlx', `${treatedline}\n`, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return;
        });
    }
}).then(function() {
    __callback()
})
```

The input and output files are XML and I will provide two pastebin URL's for the input file and output file

Input: https://pastebin.com/cHbzL1W6

Output: https://pastebin.com/C53YBwMy

These look very similar but if you run them through a file comparer some lines are switched and vise versa

Would love to fix this, Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: Unmanaged or unsequenced asynchronous operations is the likely culprit.  When multiple asynchronous operations are allowed to run in parallel, the precise order they run/complete becomes unpredictable.  The solution is to to not run them in parallel, but to sequence them so you don't start #2 until #1 finishes and so on.

Comment: For example, nothing waits for `fs.appendFile()` to finish before going onto the next operation.

Comment: I see so if I was to use `await fs.appendFile()` that could work?

Comment: No, `fs.appendFile()` won't work for two reasons.  First, it does not return a promise and `await` only does something useful if you await a promise.  You could use `await fs.promises.appendFile()` which is a different version of that function that does return a promise and does not accept a callback.  But, even that won't be enough because the `eachLine()` callback is not promise-aware and will not wait for you.  As soon as you hit that above `await`, it will immediately trigger the next line and you'll still be running multiple `appendFile()` operations at once - leading to a conflict.

Comment: I would suggest you use the readline interface and use the `for await (const line of rl) { ...}` construct shown [here](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator).  Then, you can use `await fs.promises.appendFile()` and things will be properly sequenced.  This will work if efficiency is not an important issue, but calling `fs.promises.appendFile()` for every line is very inefficient.  It has to open the file, find the length, write the new content, wait for the write and then close the file - all on every single line.

Comment: Better to open a writeStream once for the output file and write to the stream for each line, then close the writeStream when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jifriend00's first comment I saw that `fs.appendFile()` was not appending Synchronously

I fixed this by using `fs.appendFileSync()`

If anyone reading has this problem just use `fs.appendFileSync()` :D

Comment: Is this code that runs on a server?  I ask because you should never use synchronous  i/o in a server except at startup.